# Forwarding in RiscV multi cycle Pipeline

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, cpu, risc-v, pipeline

**Any idea could be helpful**

I have been trying for days to understand forwarding mechanism in RiscV but unfountly I keep failing, so I though about asking basic question to make sure I am building on correct knowledge.

In general there are 3 types of forwarding:

```
Write_Back -> Decode/Execute
Memory -> Execute
```

Can you help me know which type of data is being forwarded in each stage, for example:

```
Memory -> Execute
```

What are we moving here? the data or the location to where the data is saved?

Here's an image:

[image]

From it I can see a red lines from Memory (Addr) to the execute stage but that doesn't make sense... shouldn't we send the data instead?

Comment: If grabbing up an operand from the pipeline instead of a register was the only possible forwarding mechanism, you'd be right. But it's not. How many different types of forwarding have you considered? I don't know anything about the RISC-V architecture, but suppose, for example, that one is looping through data memory, writing a constant value at each location, using a fixed offset supplied by \$imm_X\$? It might be useful to pick off the last latched \$alu_M\$ and forward it back to the ALU. But I don't know much about RISC-V or its standardized extensions.

Comment: Hmm. I just found [WebRISC-V](http://x.dii.unisi.it:8098/~giorgi/WebRISC-V/index.php), which is quite interesting! There you can see the MAR being fed back to muxes prior to the ALU, not too unlike what you show above.

Comment: @jonk it's different than what I have here

Comment: You just made me interested in RISC-V by your question and I found a nice site for me, anyway. I'll enjoy it. However, since I'm still not yet familiar with the RV32I and RV32x extensions and must study them before I can actually point to a specific case that uses this forwarding, I'll have to allow you to work it out on your own for now. That said, I can clearly see similar mechanisms at that site. So I'm sure I will find an instruction, eventually, that illustrates the exact case you are looking for. Just not immediately as I have other work to do.

Comment: You can edit in source code (or load one of their example programs.) Once you do that, you can single step. Works fantastically well!!

Comment: now it works but I didn't understand it, as you can see in the image I have no registers 3 2 or 1 and can't understand with so much connections. For example I don't understand why wb holds 10 for the test they have to see how hazards work...

Comment: I get it. It's looks really "busy." But if you just take a moment and look at what's there slowly, I think you'll see more. They've extended the two muxes feeding the ALU so that they can select from four sources rather than two and added connections to these additional sources. They've got some added forward logic to make intelligent choices. But there's no information provided about the forward logic itself to tell you the precise cases that apply. That then requires your imagination, since the logic itself is missing.